# not getting django password reset password_reset_confirm expected error

Tags: python, django

I'm want to have a password reset using email in my django project.

In tutorials which I'm following they say, after adding `PasswordResetView` and `PasswordResetDoneView`, we must get an error contributed with `password_reset_confirm`. But I'm not getting any and code just works and there is no mail sending (I've done email configs using google app password, and sure enough at least at this point the problem is not the email). I also created required templates.

This is the expected error:

> 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a
>   valid view function or pattern name

**urls.py:**

```
path('password-reset/',
    auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
         template_name='users/password_reset.html'
     ),
     name='password_reset'),
path('password-reset/done/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
         template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'
     ),
     name='password_reset_done'),
path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
         template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'
     ),
     name='password_reset_confirm'),
path('password-reset-complete/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
         template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'
     ),
     name='password_reset_complete'),
```

**settings.py**

```
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
    EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    EMAIL_PORT = 587
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = '****'
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '****'
```

Comment: Can you post your view code as well?

Comment: thanks for your reply but I don't think that views are needed in this case, in tutorials which I was watching they didn't do any thing with views because views for these urls are already included in built-in auth views, in a simple project for just this purpose ( reset password with email ) views can be empty